# the problem with the encoding of the maven project

Tags: java, maven

I faced the following problem: I have a maven project and in my project I use ResourceBundel which in turn works with Japanese symbols. The problem is that when I run the tests, everything works correctly, the encoding when receiving Japanese characters is correct. But when I run maven clean package: in my tests, as well as in the functionality instead of Japanese characters are put "?". Help me Please.

it doesn't work for me! In IDEA settings: File encodings->Gefault encodings for property files UTF-8.

```xml
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin> 
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
   <version>3.0.0-M3</version> 
      <configuration> <encoding>UTF-8</encoding> 
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine> 
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> 
      </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the XML.

Comment: It all doesn't help.

Comment: On which JDK are you working?

Comment: I am working with jdk  1.8

Comment: Are you sure that your file is encoded in `UTF-8` ? Open with a tool like notepadd+ to see the encoding.

Comment: Yes, notepad show utf-8